# Cannot grok python multiprocessing

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce, multiprocessing

I need to run a function for the each of the elements of my database.

When I try the following:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from pymongo import Connection

def foo():
...


connection1 = Connection('127.0.0.1', 27017)
db1 = connection1.data

my_pool = Pool(6)
my_pool.map(foo, db1.index.find())
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Job 1, 'python myscript.py ' terminated by signal SIGKILL (Forced quit)

Which is, I think, caused by `db1.index.find()` eating all the available ram while trying to return millions of database elements...

How should I modify my code for it to work?

Some logs are here:

```
dmesg | tail -500 | grep memory
[177886.768927] Out of memory: Kill process 3063 (python) score 683 or sacrifice child
[177891.001379]  [<ffffffff8110e51a>] out_of_memory+0xfa/0x250
[177891.021362] Out of memory: Kill process 3063 (python) score 684 or sacrifice child
[177891.025399]  [<ffffffff8110e51a>] out_of_memory+0xfa/0x250
```

The actual function below:

```
def create_barrel(item):
    connection = Connection('127.0.0.1', 27017)
    db = connection.data
    print db.index.count()
    barrel = []
    fls = []
    if 'name' in item.keys():
        barrel.append(WhitespaceTokenizer().tokenize(item['name']))
        name = item['name']
    elif 'name.utf-8' in item.keys():
        barrel.append(WhitespaceTokenizer().tokenize(item['name.utf-8']))
        name = item['name.utf-8']
    else:
        print item.keys()
    if 'files' in item.keys():
        for file in item['files']:
            if 'path' in file.keys():
                barrel.append(WhitespaceTokenizer().tokenize(" ".join(file['path'])))
                fls.append(("\\".join(file['path']),file['length']))
            elif 'path.utf-8'  in file.keys():
                barrel.append(WhitespaceTokenizer().tokenize(" ".join(file['path.utf-8'])))
                fls.append(("\\".join(file['path.utf-8']),file['length']))
            else:
                print file
                barrel.append(WhitespaceTokenizer().tokenize(file))
    if len(fls) < 1:
        fls.append((name,item['length']))
    barrel = sum(barrel,[])
    for s in barrel:
        vs = re.findall("\d[\d|\.]*\d", s) #versions i.e. numbes such as 4.2.7500 
    b0 = []
    for s in barrel:
        b0.append(re.split("[" + string.punctuation + "]", s))
    b1 = filter(lambda x: x not in string.punctuation, sum(b0,[]))
    flag = True
    while flag:
        bb = []
        flag = False
        for bt in b1:
            if bt[0] in string.punctuation:
                bb.append(bt[1:])
                flag = True
            elif bt[-1] in string.punctuation:
                bb.append(bt[:-1])
                flag = True
            else:
                bb.append(bt)
        b1 = bb
    b2 = b1 + barrel + vs
    b3 = list(set(b2))
    b4 = map(lambda x: x.lower(), b3)
    b_final = {}
    b_final['_id'] = item['_id']
    b_final['tags'] = b4
    b_final['name'] = name
    b_final['files'] = fls
    print db.barrels.insert(b_final)
```

I've noticed interesting thing. Then I press ctrl+c to stop process I'm getting the following:

```
python index2barrel.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index2barrel.py", line 83, in <module>
    my_pool.map(create_barrel, db1.index.find, 6)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 227, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 280, in map_async
    iterable = list(iterable)
TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable
```

I mean, why multiprocessing is trying to convert somethin to the list? Isn't it the source of the problem?

from the stack trace:

```
brk(0x231ccf000)                        = 0x231ccf000
futex(0x1abb150, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
sendto(3, "+\0\0\0\260\263\355\356\0\0\0\0\325\7\0\0\0\0\0\0data.index\0\0"..., 43, 0, NULL, 0) = 43
recvfrom(3, "Some text from my database."..., 491663, 0, NULL, NULL) = 491663
... [manymany times]
brk(0x2320d5000)                        = 0x2320d5000
.... manymany times
```

The above sample goes and goes in strace output and for some reason strace -o logfile python myscript.py
does not halt. It just eats all the available ram and writes in log file.

UPDATE. Using imap instead of map solved my problem.

Comment: This is Linux, yes? Do you have anything in the system logs showing the OOM killer terminated your process?

Comment: @cha0site Yes, this is ubuntu. I will examine the logs, but from htop I saw that memory (all the 8 GBs!) was eaten in a few seconds so I think the problem is the map(...) trying to get the whole database in list. Don't how to avoid this.

Comment: I think we may need to see what `foo()` does. `find()` returns a `Cursor`, which shouldn't store all the records in memory...

Comment: @cha0site function added. 
The thing is then I try to run this code as

for item in db.index.find():


everything works fine (but slow)

Comment: A thought: is the code to create the Pool run at the top-level, not within a function (or __name__ == '__main__') clause? If so, it will also be executed by each subprocess, which is very bad. :)

Comment: @Soulman yes, exactly it is.  But I cannot understand why would that happen, I mean I'm executing only the specific function, not the whole python script, right? Or not? Could you explain?
Or is the whole multiprocessing module based on some kind of forking?

Comment: @Soulman I've tried to put it inside name == "main" clause but nothing has changed.

Comment: @Moonwalker, you mean `__name__ == "__main__"`, right?

Comment: @Moonwalker In order to run the function, each child process may need to import your module, which implies that all top-level code will be executed by each process. But apparently you only have to worry about this if your code needs to run on Windows: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `find()` operation is returning the cursor the the map function and since you say that this runs without a problem when you do 
`for item in db1.index.find(): create_barrel(item)` 
it looks like the `create_barrel` function is OK.

Can you try to limit the number of results returned in the cursor and see if this helps? I think the syntax would be:

```
db1.index.find().limit(100)
```

If you could try this and see if it helps it might help to get the cause of the problem.

EDIT1: I think you are going about this the wrong way by using the map function - I think you should be using map_reduce in the mongo python driver - that way the map function will be executed by the mongod process.

Comment: Well, that works. I need to iterate this in the loop along with skip(n*100) or something, but man, this solution feels somehow dirty :|, i mean, I've already got map function, why use loop...

Comment: I guess you could try to add 
`__len__` 
back in 
`    def __len__(self):`

`    # __len__ is deprecated (replaced with size()) and will be removed.
    #
    # The reason for this deprecation is a bit complex:
    # list(...) calls _PyObject_LengthHint to guess how much space will be
    # required for the returned list. That method in turn calls __len__.
    # Therefore, calling list(...) on a Cursor instance would require at least
    # two round trips to the database if we keep __len__ - this makes it about
    # twice as slow as [x for x in Cursor], which isn't obvious to users.`

Comment: I've tried to add '__len__' as you and Lycha suggested, but it fails `Traceback (most recent call last): File "index2barrel.py", line 86, in <module> my_pool.map(create_barrel, cursor, chunksize=10) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 227, in map return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get() File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 286, in map_async if len(iterable) == 0: TypeError: object of type 'Cursor' has no len()` I've tried to add len function myself but with no luck.

Comment: Mongo's map_reduce function must be written in js, but I want to use python because of libraries. Thanks for a advice though, idea with limit is working.

Answer (score 1):

[map()](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) function gives the items in chunks to the given function. By default this chunksize is calculated like this ([link to source](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release26-maint/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py)):

```
chunksize, extra = divmod(len(iterable), len(self._pool) * 4)
```

This probably results in too big chunk size in your case and lets the process run out of memory. Try setting the chunk size manually like this:

```
my_pool.map(foo, db1.index.find(), 100)
```

EDIT: You should also consider reusing the db connection and closing them after usage. Now you create new db connection for each item, and you don't call `close()` to them.

EDIT2: Also check if the `while` loop gets into an infinite loop (would explain the symptoms).

EDIT3: Based on the traceback you added the map function tries to convert the cursor to a list, causing all the items to be fetched at once. This happens because it want's to find how many items there are in the set. This is part of `map()` code from [pool.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py?view=markup):

```
if not hasattr(iterable, '__len__'):
    iterable = list(iterable)
```

You could try this to avoid conversion to list:

```
cursor = db1.index.find()
cursor.__len__ = cursor.count()
my_pool.map(foo, cursor)
```

Comment: I've tried this (and even with chunk size = 6) and got the same problem: python starts additional processes (up to the specified amount, i.e. 6 in my example) which are eating ram till no ram left and all thing halts. 

When I just run this function the for loop ram consumption is almost unnoticeable.

Comment: @Moonwalker I added one more note about usage of db connections.

Comment: I've even removed db connection from the function to see whether it works, but no luck :( 
It seems that function does nothing, not a single element being written in the database...

Comment: @Moonwalker Ok, in that case I'd check if the `while` loop gets into an infinite loop. Have you checked that?

Comment: Yes, I've checked that. 
This version works perfectly:

for item in db1.index.find():
    create_barrel(item)

Comment: can you run: strace python <script.py> (sub for your python) and paste the output when this is getting killed?

Comment: @Moonwalker I added one more suggestion, based on the Stacktrace.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index2barrel.py", line 86, in <module>
    my_pool.map(create_barrel, cursor, chunksize=10)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 227, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 286, in map_async
    if len(iterable) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'Cursor' has no len()

I've tried to add len function myself but with no luck.